# How to send a POST request using JSON format in PHP

Tags: php, json, post

I have been able to use the Advanced Rest Client Extension for chrome to send POST queries to an specific URL and this following code:

As headers I entered this:

```
Accept: application/json
version: 1.0.2
Authorization: code sadkj4-sadj-as22-asdk2
```

as the body:

```
{
   "email" : "$email",    <====PHP variable passed as argument
   "password" : "$password",  <====PHP variable passed as argument
   "UserVerified" : true, 
   "notificationOption" :
      [
         {
            "notificationType" : "NOTIFICATION1",
            "enabled" : true
         },
         {
            "notificationType" : "NOTIFICATION2",
            "enabled" : false
         },
         {
            "notificationType" : "NOTIFICATION3",
            "enabled" : true
         },
         {
            "notificationType" : "NOTIFICATION4",
            "enabled" : true
         },
         {
            "notificationType" : "NOTIFICATION5",
            "enabled" : true
         },
         {
            "notificationType" : "NOTIFICATION6",
            "enabled" : true
         }
      ],
    "cap":"uc",
    "GeneratedPassword":true
}
```

and set Content-Type to: application/json

I successfully get a response by the URL I sent the request to, but now I would like to create a PHP function which can do that by just passing the values $email and $password as arguments.

I've heard people that says I should use guzzle for this task but I don't know how to do it and also I wouldn't like to use 3rd party libraries if I don't need to. Is there any other way to do this?
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cURL`, if possible. Prepare your json data including email/password in `$json_string_data`

```
$json_string_data = '{"email" : "' . $email . '", "password" : "' . $password . '", ...}';
$ch = curl_init('http://your_api_url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'version: 1.0.2',
    'Authorization: code sadkj4-sadj-as22-asdk2',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_string_data))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I was wondering where you put the body in this case?

Comment: In this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string_data);

Answer (score 0):

You need a HTTP client library to interact with web server, guzzle is one of them, another example is Zend\Http. It could be messy if you do it without libraries because then you have to manage HTTP headers, body, url, etc. yourself.

The next easiest way is to use PHP curl library and the hard core way would be implementing everything using PHP socket.